# How to connect magento 2 to Redis

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, magento2

I have a magento 2 installation on docker, i would like to work with redis api, but not for magento2's session or page caching.
I would like to use the `get()` and `set()` commands to store strings, hash tables and many more.
Majorly what i need is a way to connect to a redis installed on docker instance that is on the same network as a magento 2 installation which is also on docker.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Redis docker, maybe this will help you:

```
'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => 'redis',
            'port' => '6379',
            'password' => '',
            'timeout' => '2.5',
            'persistent_identifier' => '',
            'database' => '0',
            'compression_threshold' => '2048',
            'compression_library' => 'gzip',
            'log_level' => '1',
            'max_concurrency' => '10',
            'break_after_frontend' => '5',
            'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
            'first_lifetime' => '600',
            'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
            'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
            'disable_locking' => '1',
            'min_lifetime' => '60',
            'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
        ]
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => 'redis',
                    'database' => '1',
                    'port' => '6379'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Regards

Comment: thanks @Lee, but i don't to use redis for the frontend/backend and session cache. I just want to connect to it straight like connecting to an external API or resource.

Comment: Did you try to access your redis docker? If not, you can connect your redis by run this command `docker exec -it your_docker_redis bash` and then you can access redis server by run this `redis-cli`, and then you can use `get`, `set` command

Comment: Yes i know i can use those commands on my redis container, but i mean how can i use the `get` `set` inside magento2 i.e using php codes to set keys and get the values from it. basically what i need is a connection or an Adapter to the redis container inside magento 2, but not using the cache section of  magento 2 cos it forces you to use sessions.

Comment: Try this: `$redis = new Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis([
    'server' => 'redis',
    'database' => '1',
    'port' => '6379'
]);

$redis->save('test_data', 'your_id');

echo $redis->load('your_id');`